# looking for an nservicebus example with subscriptions

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I've followed the following tutorial and I've succesfully seen the console update saying what it expects although looking at the actual queues I cannot see any subscriptions or messages being passed through.  I'm guessing this tutorial (see link below) is using a different approach with nservicebus.  Is there a tutorial or something I can follow that uses subscriptions so that I can monitor messages travelling through the queues?

http://docs.particular.net/samples/

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you don't see messages in the queue is that the process immediately pulls the messages off of the queue.

Comment: yes true but I can't see any subscriptions within the queues?

Comment: Subscriptions aren't stored within the queues either. A subscription message is sent to the publisher endpoint, processed immediately, and then stored in subscription storage. Depending upon the profile you're running in, this is either in memory or in RavenDB by default.

Comment: ok thanks, is there anyway to see what approach is being used and what the subscriptions look like? thanks

Comment: If you didn't explicitly set the profile to Lite by running with `NServiceBus.Lite` in the command line, then you are likely using the Production profile, which means RavenDB. You can verify this by looking at the console output, and there will be a line that says something like "Validating connection to RavenDB". Assuming Raven, go to http://localhost:8080 to access the Raven Management Studio.